# Nuget Packages missing for IOS in Xamarin Forms Solution in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

For some reason that I haven't been able to figure out my packages seem to be missing. If I click 'Restore Packages' everything works fine.

If I add 1 more, it shows that thats the only package I have. I just don't have the option to update packages through the Package Manager.

Here is what I have:

[image]

I have researched havent found anything. My droid project works fine. I have compared both .csproj and they seem very similar. Here is the section where the packages are:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS" />
    <Reference Include="Plugin.MediaManager.Abstractions">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Plugin.MediaManager.0.4.5\lib\Xamarin.iOS10\Plugin.MediaManager.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.MediaManager">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Plugin.MediaManager.0.4.5\lib\Xamarin.iOS10\Plugin.MediaManager.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.Settings.Abstractions">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xam.Plugins.Settings.3.1.1\lib\Xamarin.iOS10\Plugin.Settings.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.Settings">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xam.Plugins.Settings.3.1.1\lib\Xamarin.iOS10\Plugin.Settings.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Does anyone has a clue on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Step one would be checking for updates for Visual Studio. Also, do you have a `packages.config` or `project.json` in your project directory

Comment: @BenCampsI have the last version of Visual Studio. I have a packages.config in the iOS folder:
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="BTProgressHUD" version="1.2.0.6" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="CarouselView.FormsPlugin" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AppCenter" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
```

Comment: Try to remove all the reference and reinstall them in package manager .

Comment: I would look in the IDE log for errors. Possibly the packages.config file cannot be read. Also after you install the new NuGet package where does that information get stored? Is it in the packages.config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments. I have found the problem.

A few weeks ago, I got some errors while building the solution and one of the recommended solution was to add this to the .csproj:

`<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>`

That turn out to be the culprit of the problem. I removed that line and everything started to work again.

Comment: Could you accept this as answer ? It is helpful to the people who faces the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion